# Why does enum value need to be coerced before object type is recognized properly?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an object that is discriminated on the `type` property which can be any value of a given enum. When I create a valid object and then pass it to a function, typescript complains that the types don't match. However, if I coerce the enum value then it's fine.

```js
enum AorB {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
};

type Bar_A = {
  type: AorB.A;
};

type Bar_B = {
  type: AorB.B;
}

type Bar = Bar_A | Bar_B;

function foo(a: Bar): void {}

const arg = {
  type: AorB.A,
};

// this would work but is extra writing
// const arg = {
//   type: AorB.A as AorB.A
// };

foo(arg); // Error
foo({
  type: AorB.A,
})
```

See the equivalent [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20AorB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20A%20%3D%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20B%20%3D%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bar_A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20AorB.A%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bar_B%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20AorB.B%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20Bar_A%20%7C%20Bar_B%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20Bar)%3A%20void%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arg%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20AorB.A%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(arg)%3B%0D%0Afoo(%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20AorB.A%2C%0D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will widen literal types unless it has a reason to keep them around so `arg` will be typed as `{type: AorB }` not `{ type: AorB.A, }`.

If you explicitly use a type assertion `AorB.A as AorB.A` then typescript will preserve the literal type. If you assign the object literal to a location that requires `Bar` (such as the parameter to the function) typescript will again preserve the literal type.

Another option that will work is to type `arg` explicitly:

```
const arg: Bar = {
  type: AorB.A,
};

foo(arg);
foo({
  type: AorB.A,
})
```

Or use `as const` in 3.4 to get the compiler to keep literal types without having to specify the type again, although that will make the whole object readonly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `as const`. I get this error: `A 'const' assertion can only be applied to a string, number, boolean, array, or object literal.`

I dont really understand why `AorB.A` is widened to `AorB`. It doesn't seem useful, but I'm sure there are some consequences I haven't though of :)

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Awinograd `{
  type: AorB.A,
} as const` works. `{
  type: AorB.A as const,
}` does not currently work but will soon https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30690#issuecomment-478780400

Comment: Ahh you're right! Not sure how I missed trying that (even though it says so in the error message). Thanks @Titian